# jQueryJavaScript error - missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using this statement in my code to cache the jquery selector and this was causing an error in the console. The error was `"Missing ; before statement"`

```
var $medium-image-holder = $('#image_'+itemID_value);
```

where `itemID_value` is a numeric value. This statement is inside a for loop

Out of curiosity and after trying various tricks to overcome this thing, I replaced the hyphen with underscore in the variable name.

```
var $medium_image_holder = $('#image_'+itemID_value);
```

Surprisingly this worked.

I want to know whether using hyphens in JavaScript variable names is not permitted. At least, I didn't know about this. Would be very helpful if someone clarifies.

Comment: err '-' is not a hyphen it's minus! it's not a valid javascript identifier character.

Comment: @AhmedMasud It's actually called the hyphen-minus character http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus

Comment: @PenchoIlchev i was being specific to javascript, i wasn't talking about the character itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement `$medium-image-holder` is interpreted as `$medium - image - holder` ($medium minus image minus holder).

After interpreting this statement as an algebraic expression, you try to set the outcome of it to a value with another statement (`=$('#image_'+itemID_value)`), which is not allowed. That is where your error message comes from.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. but the error msg is misguiding. what do you say? how do you correlate the error msg with funda?

Comment: Yes, the error message is misleading, but that is the case with error messages sometimes. Delete a semicolon or a closing bracket in Pascal or C code and then try to find the error in your code.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, hyphens are **not** allowed in variable names.

Comment: Thanks, but this was obviously a typo.

Answer (score 3):

[MDC Guidelines for variable names state;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Variables)

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).

Comment: i knew the this but I interpreted it as if we can use - in the middle of the string

Answer (score 0):

java script does not allow hyphen in variable name declaration variable name can only include alphabets numbers or underscore moreover variable name should only start with alphabet variable names cannot start with numbers

cheers